# android how to update textview from another activity

Tags: android

how to update textview from another activity help me please i want if condition sucessfull in another classs change textview value this code not work for me please help me

```
    public class NotificationDetail extends Activity {
    public static   TextView pickpplots, destinatonplots;

         pickpplots = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pickuppointplot);
        destinatonplots = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.destinationplot);



      pickpplots.setText(pickuplist.get(1));
            destinatonplots.setText(destlist.get(1));



 now i want in second activity if condition true change textview values 



         public class LatlongService extends Service {



String  Pikup,Dest,Pickupdate,Cust,Mob;

  Pikup=listmessang.get(3);

        Dest=listmessang.get(4);

          if (NotificationDetail.not_detail != null)
                            {



            NotificationDetail.pickpplots.setText("");

        NotificationDetail.destinatonplots.setText("");

       NotificationDetail.pickpplots.setText(Pikup.toString());

       NotificationDetail.destinatonplots.setText(Dest.toString());
```

Comment: u can use handler to post the message from any where in your application.

Comment: Use static variable and store your value inside it, and then check in your first activity whether the text is changed in other activity or not if yes then do whatever task you want to perform.

Comment: I tried the static variable, it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for saving data, or create `public static String data;` in your activity, then you have access to that field across whole application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are new to android.

See we can use a Util class
say

```
public class AppUtils{
    public Static String string1="default text";
}
```

now set this value from the activity you want. Say inside activity that doesn't has reference of that TextView you want to change

```
public void onButtonOneClick(){
    AppUtils.string1 = "Desired String";
}
```

and use in the activity which holds the TextView.

```
textView1.setText(AppUtils.string1);
```